# How to prevent a lone table on its own page?

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I have a tabular that is automatically drawn on a sole new page. I would like on the same page as my text

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, french]{article}
%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\selectlanguage{french}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\title{Choisir le meilleur candidat pour un électeur}
\author{Antoine Coppin, Elhadj Oumar Diallo}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
"Élections, piège à cons." Cette expression des manifestants soixante-huitards exprimait leur rancoeur envers un système qui ne représentait plus leurs aspirations. Quarante ans après le problème de la représentation du choix des électeurs lors des élections pose toujours problème: en France c'était l'engagement numéro 48 du candidat Hollande: «J'introduirai une part de proportionnelle à l'Assemblée nationale.» Le journal Le Monde jugeait la proposition juste puisqu'elle "semble plus conforme aux votes des citoyens et favorise la parité, puisque les listes font alterner hommes et femmes."

Le problème de sous-représentation ou de mal-représentation prend même une dimension international si l'on constate que les éléctions américaines de 2001 ou de 2016 furent reportées par des candidats remportant le plus grand nombre d'états selon la règle du "Winner takes all" tout en perdant au niveau du vote populaire.  

Mais plus encore, la manière dont sont représentés les électeurs étant votée par les élus eux-mêmes, il faut mesurer toute la sensibilité d'un tel sujet ou il serait souhaitable que les représentants incarnent le choix des électeurs sachant qu'il est peu probable qu'un candidat incarnent tous les désirs politiques d'un électeur, il est même probable d'être d'accord avec le différentes parties des programmes de différents candidats tout en étant en désaccord avec d'autres parties.

En définitive, à chaque éléction, la difficulté est d'une part de choisir au mieux un candidat sachant que d'autre part on n'est jamais complètement en accord avec son programme et que d'autres propositions concurrentes peuvent nous tourner vers un autre candidat.

Ainsi quel processus de décision pourrait permettre d'aider au choix d'un candidat lors d'élection?

L'objectif est donc de créer un outil permettant d'aider la décision d'un choix de candidat. Nous prendrons un exemple d'actualité : la primaire de la gauche. L'information disponible pour créer cet outil a été d'avoir eu accès aux programmes de tous les candidats, notamment grâce à leur sites de campagnes. Il n'y a ici qu'un seul acteur à chaque fois, une seule personne est amenée à prendre une décision : l'électeur. Son système de valeur est défini par les réponses qu'il apporte aux questions sur les programmes des candidats qui forment les critères.

\newpage

\section{Le meilleur processus de décision repose sur une méthode multicritère d'aggrégation et de surclassement}

\subsection{L'analyse du problème et la méthode utilisée pour la solution}

Dès le départ le problème a été cerné comme un problème de décision multicritère :
l'électeur est confronté a des dizaines de propositions tirées des programmes des candidats et ils doit évaluer ces proposition, s'il est d'accord ou non, si celles-ci sont importantes pour lui ou non. Finalement, l'électeur doit choisir lequel des programmes est préféré à tous les autres.
Il fallait donc évaluer des critères et leur attribuer des poids et comparer les évaluations. Par analogie, il s'agissait d'un problème de décision multicritère.

Il fallait choisir entre faire des matrices de discordances où seule une ligne nous interressait : celle de l'électeur ou bien s'il était préférable de faire des matrices complètes de performances de chaque candidat par rapports aux attentes de l'électeur pour le critère. Cette dernière option a été choisit dans la mesure ou elle permet de créer une matrice de surclassement et d'appliquer la théorie des graphes pour savoir quel candidat surclasse tout le monde.



\subsection{Les variables et le principe de calcul et de résultat}

\subsubsection{L'évaluation du score des candidats aux questions}
Les propositions de campagnes des candidats ont alors été listées et donnée sous forme de questions, il s'agit dès lors pour l'électeur de choisir s'il est d'accord avec elles et de leur attribuer un poids d'importance.

Ainsi les variables d'entrées sont les suivantes :

\begin{itemize}
\item $reponse_{q,p}\in{[\![ -1;1 ]\!]}$ le désaccord, l'indiférence ou l'accord de la personne $p\in \{\{ candidat_1; candidat_n \} \bigcup Electeur\}$  avec la question $q$.
\item $w_q\in \{\{ 1; 5 \}$ le poids d'importance associé à la question $q$
\end{itemize}

Par exemple à la première question de l'outil : \textit{"Production d'électricité 100\% renouvelable?"}, si le votant est pour et trouve la question peu importante le résultat à la question est :

\begin{align*}
w_1*reponse_{1,electeur}&=1*1\\
&=1
\end{align*}
Mais si le votant est contre et trouve la question fondamentale le résultat à la question est

\begin{align*}
w_1*reponse_{1,electeur}&=5*-1\\
&=-5
\end{align*}
Et si la question fait partie du programme d'un candidat on lui donne tout de suite le maximum de points.

\begin{align*}
w_1*reponse_{1,DeRugy}&=5*1\\
&=5
\end{align*}

\subsubsection{Le score des candidats par thème}

Il a été choisi d'abord de faire des matrices de concordance par thème (écologie, économie...) pour être capable d'expliquer par modularité les points d'accords ou de désaccord avec le candidat. Pour cela il fallait calculer le score de chaque candidat par thème par rapport aux réponses du votant aux questions sur les programmes.

Ainsi les variables d'entrées sont les mêmes. Mais elles sont regroupés par thème pour donner la formule suivante :

$$Score_{theme}(electeur, candidat_i)=\sum_{q\in ecologie}|w_q*reponse_{q,candidat_i}+w_q*reponse_{q,electeur}|$$

Cette formule permet de dresser un tableau croisant le score des candidats par thème par rapport aux préférences du votant. L'écart de préférence est fait par la formule de l'addition dans la valeur absolue. Si le votant est pour une proposition ainsi que le candidat (cette proposition fait partie de son programme) alors les deux résultats à la question pondérés par les poids s'ajoutent. Au contraire, si le votant est contre une proposition du candidat alors les deux résultats à la question pondérés par les poids s'annulent. Si la proposition ne fait pas partie du programme du candidat alors la somme des résultats sera positif comme tout autre candidat n'ayant pas cette proposition.

Par exemple :

Soit le tableau suivant appliqués à un ensemble de question $[\![ 1;3 ]\!]\in ecologie$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& q_1 & q_2 & q_3\\
\hline
reponse_{q,electeur}& 1 & 1 & -1\\
\hline
reponse_{q,Valls} & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
w_q & 1 & 5& 3\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

\begin{align*}
Score_{ecologie}(electeur, Valls)&=\sum_{q\in ecologie}|w_q*reponse_{q,Valls}+w_q*reponse_{q,electeur}|\\
&=|1*1+1*1|+|5*1+5*1|+|0*3-1*3|\\
&=15
\end{align*}

\subsubsection{Les matrice de concordance, non-discordance et de surclassement}

Riche de cette méthode d'évaluation des scores des candidats par rapport aux préférences de l'électeur sur des thèmes, nous pouvons dresser des matrices de concordances par thèmes, de non-discordance et de surclassement.

Les matrices de concordance permettent de savoir si une majorité de critères, compte-tenu de leur importance, peuvent supporter l’assertion $aSb$. Nous pouvons calculer la matrice de concordance $c_{theme}(candidat_i,candidat_j)$, c'est à dire :"$candidat_i$ est au moins aussi bon que $candidat_j$ sur $theme_i$" qui est égal à $1$ si c'est vrai , $0$ sinon. C'est à dire :
$$c_{theme}(candidat_i,candidat_j)=$$
$$\begin{cases}
1 &\mbox{si } Score_{theme}(electeur, candidat_i)+seuil\ge Score_{theme}(electeur, candidat_j)\\
0 &\mbox{sinon}
\end{cases}$$

Ensuite nous pouvons calculer la matrice de concordance globale, $C(candidat_i,candidat_j)$.

$$C(candidat_i, candidat_j)=\frac{1}{\sum_{t\in theme} w_t}\sum_{t\in theme} w_{t}c_{t}(candidat_i, candidat_j)$$

Par exemple : soit On cherche à faire $C_{ecologie}$ à partir du tableau des résultats suivant et un seuil de $0$:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& Economie & Ecologie & Social\\
\hline
Valls & 21 & 15 & 13\\
\hline
Peillon & 12 & 21 & 0\\
\hline
Montebourg & 31 & 52 & 33\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

On a alors 

$$C_{ecologie}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

$C(candidat_i, candidat_j)$ exprime dans quelle mesure les performances de $candidat_i$ et $candidat_j$ sur tous les critères sont en concordance avec "$candidat_i$ surclasse $candidat_j$".

Cela nous permet de construire la matrice de non-discordance, c'est à dire la matrice des critères non-concordants (discordant) qui refute fortement $aSb$ (principe de respect des minorites). Pour chaque thème $t$ on regarde si le score du rival ne dépasse pas un certain seuil de véto $v_t$. C'est à dire:

$$D_{candidat_i,candidat_j}=
\begin{cases}
1 \mbox{ si }\exists t, Score_{t}(electeur, candidat_i)+v_t< Score_{t}(electeur, candidat_j)\\
0 \mbox{ sinon }
\end{cases}$$

Par exemple : dans notre outil nous avons pris comme seuil de véto $20\%$ du score de l'électeur avec lui-même, le maximum de points qui puisse être donné. Donc si un candidat présente des résultats à un thème ou ceui-ci est moins bon qu'un autre candidat malgré une marge de $20\%$, alors il y a discordance.

Enfin la matrice de surclassement est établie à partir des deux dernières matrices de concordance et de surclassement ainsis qu'à partir du seuil de majorité à partir duquel un candidat.

$$S_{candidat_i,candidat_j}=
\begin{cases}
0 \mbox{ si } D_{candidat_i,candidat_j} = 1 \mbox{ ou } C(candidat_i, candidat_j) < s_{maj}\\
1 \mbox{ sinon }
\end{cases}$$




\section{Mise en oeuvre et résultats}

La mise en oeuvre s'est faite de manière exhaustive sur toutes les propositions des candidats soit $102$ questions associées à un même nombre de mesure d'importance de la question. Ces questions ont été regroupés en $9$ thèmes:

\begin{itemize}
\item Ecologie
\item Travail
\item International
\item Institution
\item Santé
\item Economie
\item Social
\item Sécurité
\item Education
\end{itemize}

Les variables de résultats sont les suivantes

\begin{table}
\caption{Table des scores des candidats par thèmes}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
           & Ecologie & Travail & Interna. & Instit. & Santé & Eco. & Social & Sécurité & Education \\
Pinel      & 19       & 24      & 31            & 35          & 14    & 29       & 17     & 15       & 9         \\
Bennahmias & 19       & 23      & 26            & 43          & 14    & 29       & 11     & 15       & 9         \\
de Rugy    & 25       & 25      & 26            & 49          & 14    & 37       & 11     & 15       & 16        \\
Valls      & 19       & 23      & 26            & 42          & 19    & 29       & 11     & 15       & 9         \\
Peillon    & 19       & 23      & 27            & 40          & 20    & 30       & 15     & 15       & 8         \\
Montebourg & 19       & 20      & 26            & 47          & 19    & 35       & 17     & 18       & 9         \\
Hamon      & 23       & 17      & 30            & 43          & 15    & 27       & 11     & 23       & 9         \\
Electeur   & 37       & 51      & 52            & 78          & 28    & 58       & 25     & 30       & 17       
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Ce qui permet de dresser la matrice de concordance suivante : 

\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot :

[image: display]

I tried to force the position with `\begin{table}[!h]` but it didn't worked.

Comment: Your title does not fit the description. The title says 'center', the description is 'I want to keep on the same place'.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What should I wrote ? I wrote "not to center"

Comment: We can't help if we don't have a *full* code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Marine1: See [Float placement](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I read the parargraph and tried to give a specific position but it wasn't better `\begin{table}[!h]`

Answer (score 4):

Your problem won't happen if there is text following the table, and if you add the placement option `[!htb]`. However, in case the table ends the chapter, you can add this code to your preamble, to prevent a lonely table/ figure on one page be vertically centred:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}
\makeatother
```

Some comments aside: *don't* use `$$ … $$`  for displayed equations: it is plain TeX code, and it can lead to bad vertical spacing. Use the LaTeX code `\[ … \]` instead. Also, don't add a blank line before a displayed equation, as it will increase the vertical spacing w.r.t. the surrounding text. In equations, use  `\text{…}` or `\textit{…}` for variable names which are actually ordinary words. I also too the liberty to correct some typos and misspellings. Note you should not drop accents in capital letters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, french]{article}
%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage{babel}
\selectlanguage{french}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm, hmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm, showframe]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs} \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\title{Choisir le meilleur candidat pour un électeur}
\author{Antoine Coppin, Elhadj Oumar Diallo}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
« Élections, piège à cons. » Cette expression des manifestants soixante-huitards exprimait leur rancœur envers un système qui ne représentait plus leurs aspirations. Quarante ans après le problème de la représentation du choix des électeurs lors des élections pose toujours problème: en France c'était l'engagement numéro 48 du candidat Hollande: «J'introduirai une part de proportionnelle à l'Assemblée nationale.» Le journal Le Monde jugeait la proposition juste puisqu'elle «semble plus conforme aux votes des citoyens et favorise la parité, puisque les listes font alterner hommes et femmes.»

Le problème de sous-représentation ou de mal-représentation prend même une dimension international si l'on constate que les éléctions américaines de 2001 ou de 2016 furent reportées par des candidats remportant le plus grand nombre d'états selon la règle du \emph{Winner takes all} tout en perdant au niveau du vote populaire.

Mais plus encore, la manière dont sont représentés les électeurs étant votée par les élus eux-mêmes, il faut mesurer toute la sensibilité d'un tel sujet où il serait souhaitable que les représentants incarnent le choix des électeurs sachant qu'il est peu probable qu'un candidat incarne tous les désirs politiques d'un électeur, il est même probable d'être d'accord avec les différentes parties des programmes de différents candidats tout en étant en désaccord avec d'autres parties.

En définitive, à chaque élection, la difficulté est d'une part de choisir au mieux un candidat, sachant que d'autre part on n'est jamais complètement en accord avec son programme et que d'autres propositions concurrentes peuvent nous tourner vers un autre candidat.

Ainsi quel processus de décision pourrait permettre d'aider au choix d'un candidat lors d'élection ?

L'objectif est donc de créer un outil permettant d'aider la décision d'un choix de candidat. Nous prendrons un exemple d'actualité : la primaire de la gauche. L'information disponible pour créer cet outil a été d'avoir eu accès aux programmes de tous les candidats, notamment grâce à leur sites de campagnes. Il n'y a ici qu'un seul acteur à chaque fois, une seule personne est amenée à prendre une décision : l'électeur. Son système de valeurs est défini par les réponses qu'il apporte aux questions sur les programmes des candidats qui forment les critères.

\newpage

\section{Le meilleur processus de décision repose sur une méthode multicritère d'aggrégation et de surclassement}

\subsection{L'analyse du problème et la méthode utilisée pour la solution}

Dès le départ le problème a été cerné comme un problème de décision multicritère : l'électeur est confronté a des dizaines de propositions tirées des programmes des candidats et ils doivent évaluer ces propositions, s'il est d'accord ou non, si celles-ci sont importantes pour lui ou non. Finalement, l'électeur doit choisir lequel des programmes est préféré à tous les autres.
Il fallait donc évaluer des critères et leur attribuer des poids et comparer les évaluations. Par analogie, il s'agissait d'un problème de décision multicritère.

Il fallait choisir entre faire des matrices de discordances où seule une ligne nous intéressait : celle de l'électeur, ou bien s'il était préférable de faire des matrices complètes de performances de chaque candidat par rapport aux attentes de l'électeur pour le critère. Cette dernière option a été choisie dans la mesure où elle permet de créer une matrice de surclassement et d'appliquer la théorie des graphes pour savoir quel candidat surclasse tout le monde.

\subsection{Les variables et le principe de calcul et de résultat}

\subsubsection{L'évaluation du score des candidats aux questions}
Les propositions de campagnes des candidats ont alors été listées et donnée sous forme de questions. il s'agit dès lors pour l'électeur de choisir s'il est d'accord avec elles et de leur attribuer un poids d'importance.

Ainsi les variables d'entrées sont les suivantes :

\begin{itemize}
\item $reponse_{q,p}\in{[\![ -1;1 ]\!]}$ le désaccord, l'indifférence ou l'accord de la personne $p\in \{\{ \text{candidat}_1; \text{candidat}_n \} \bigcup \text{Électeur}\}$ avec la question $q$.
\item $w_q\in \{\{ 1; 5 \}$ le poids d'importance associé à la question $q$
\end{itemize}

Par exemple à la première question de l'outil : \textit{"Production d'électricité 100\% renouvelable?"}, si le votant est pour et trouve la question peu importante le résultat à la question est :
\begin{align*}
w_1*\text{réponse}_{1,\text{électeur}}&=1*1\\
&=1
\end{align*}
Mais si le votant est contre et trouve la question fondamentale le résultat à la question est
\begin{align*}
w_1*\text{réponse}_{1,\text{électeur}}&=5*-1\\
&=-5
\end{align*}
Et si la question fait partie du programme d'un candidat on lui donne tout de suite le maximum de points.
\begin{align*}
w_1*\text{réponse}_{1,\text{DeRugy}}&=5*1\\
&=5
\end{align*}

\subsubsection{Le score des candidats par thème}

Il a été choisi d'abord de faire des matrices de concordance par thème (écologie, économie,…) pour être capable d'expliquer par modularité les points d'accord ou de désaccord avec le candidat. Pour cela il fallait calculer le score de chaque candidat par thème par rapport aux réponses du votant aux questions sur les programmes.

Ainsi les variables d'entrées sont les mêmes. Mais elles sont regroupées par thème pour donner la formule suivante :
%
\[ Score_{theme}(\text{électeur}, \text{candidat}_i)=\sum_{q\in \text{écologie}}|w_q*\text{réponse}_{q,\text{candidat}_i}+w_q*\text{réponse}_{q,\text{électeur}}| \]
%
Cette formule permet de dresser un tableau croisant le score des candidats par thème par rapport aux préférences du votant. L'écart de préférence est fait par la formule de l'addition dans la valeur absolue. Si le votant est pour une proposition ainsi que le candidat (cette proposition fait partie de son programme), alors les deux résultats à la question pondérés par les poids s'ajoutent. Au contraire, si le votant est contre une proposition du candidat, alors les deux résultats à la question pondérés par les poids s'annulent. Si la proposition ne fait pas partie du programme du candidat alors la somme des résultats sera positive comme tout autre candidat n'ayant pas cette proposition.

Par exemple :

Soit le tableau suivant appliqués à un ensemble de question $[\![ 1;3 ]\!]\in \text{écologie}$
\[ \begin{array}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
& q_1 & q_2 & q_3\\
\hline
\text{réponse}_{q,\text{électeur}}& 1 & 1 & -1\\
\hline
\text{réponse}_{q,\text{Vall}s} & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{w_q} & 1 & 5& 3\\
\hline
\end{array} \]

\begin{align*}
\text{Score}_\text{écologie}(\text{électeur}, \text{Valls})&=\sum_{q\in \text{écologie}}|w_q*\text{réponse}_{q,\text{Valls}}+w_q*\text{réponse}_{q,\text{électeur}}|\\
&=|1*1+1*1|+|5*1+5*1|+|0*3-1*3|\\
&=15
\end{align*}

\subsubsection{Les matrices de concordance, non-discordance et de surclassement}

Riche de cette méthode d'évaluation des scores des candidats par rapport aux préférences de l'électeur sur des thèmes, nous pouvons dresser des matrices de concordances par thèmes, de non-discordance et de surclassement.

Les matrices de concordance permettent de savoir si une majorité de critères, compte-tenu de leur importance, peuvent supporter l’assertion $aSb$. Nous pouvons calculer la matrice de concordance $c_{theme}(candidat_i,candidat_j)$, c'est à dire :"$\text{candidat}_i$ est au moins aussi bon que $\text{candidat}_j$ sur $theme_i$" qui est égal à $1$ si c'est vrai , $0$ sinon. C'est-à-dire :
\begin{align*} \shortintertext{$ c_\text{theme}(\text{candidat}_i,\text{candidat}_j)= $}%
\begin{cases}
1 &\mbox{si } Score_{theme}(\text{électeur}, \text{candidat}_i)+seuil\ge Score_{theme}(\text{électeur}, \text{candidat}_j)\\
0 &\mbox{sinon}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Ensuite nous pouvons calculer la matrice de concordance globale, $C(\text{candidat}_i,\text{candidat}_j)$.

\[ C(\text{candidat}_i, \text{candidat}_j)=\frac{1}{\sum_{t\in theme} w_t}\sum_{t\in theme} w_{t}c_{t}(\text{candidat}_i, \text{candida}_j) \]

Par exemple : soit on cherche à faire $C_\text{écologie}$ à partir du tableau des résultats suivant et un seuil de $0$:
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
& Économie & Écologie & Social\\
\hline
Valls & 21 & 15 & 13\\
\hline
Peillon & 12 & 21 & 0\\
\hline
Montebourg & 31 & 52 & 33\\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{center}

On a alors

\[ C_\text{écologie}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \]

$C(\text{candidat}_i, \text{candidat}_j)$ exprime dans quelle mesure les performances de $\text{candidat}_i$ et $\text{candidat}_j$ sur tous les critères sont en concordance avec «candidat$_i$ surclasse candidat$_j$ ».
kk
Cela nous permet de construire la matrice de non-discordance, c'est à dire la matrice des critères non-concordants (discordant) qui refute fortement $aSb$ (principe de respect des minorités). Pour chaque thème $t$ on regarde si le score du rival ne dépasse pas un certain seuil de veto $v_t$. C'est-à-dire:
\[ D_{\text{candidat}_i,\text{candidat}_j}=
\begin{cases}
1 \mbox{ si }\exists t, Score_{t}(\text{électeur}, \text{candidat}_i)+v_t< Score_{t}(\text{électeur}, \text{candidat}_j)\\
0 \mbox{ sinon }
\end{cases} \] %
%
Par exemple : dans notre outil nous avons pris comme seuil de veto $20\%$ du score de l'électeur avec lui-même, le maximum de points qui puisse être donné. Donc si un candidat présente des résultats à un thème ou celui-ci est moins bon qu'un autre candidat malgré une marge de $20\,\%$, alors il y a discordance.

Enfin la matrice de surclassement est établie à partir des deux dernières matrices de concordance et de surclassement ainsi qu'à partir du seuil de majorité à partir duquel un candidat.
%
\[ S_{\text{candidat}_i,\text{candidat}_j}=
\begin{cases}
0 & \mbox{ si } D_{\text{candidat}_i, \text{candidat}_j} = 1 \mbox{ ou } C(\text{candidat}_i, \text{candidat}_j) < s_{maj}\\
1 & \mbox{sinon}
\end{cases} \] 

\section{Mise en œuvre et résultats}

La mise en œuvre s'est faite de manière exhaustive sur toutes les propositions des candidats, soit $102$ questions associées à un même nombre de mesures d'importance de la question. Ces questions ont été regroupées en $9$ thèmes:

\begin{itemize}
\item Écologie
\item Travail
\item International
\item Institution
\item Santé
\item Économie
\item Social
\item Sécurité
\item Éducation
\end{itemize}

Les variables de résultats sont les suivantes : 
\begin{table}[!htb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\centering
\caption{Table des scores des candidats par thèmes}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{9}{c}}
           & Écologie & Travail & Interna. & Instit. & Santé & Éco. & Social & Sécurité & Éduc. \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-10}
Pinel & 19 & 24 & 31 & 35 & 14 & 29 & 17 & 15 & 9 \\
Bennahmias & 19 & 23 & 26 & 43 & 14 & 29 & 11 & 15 & 9 \\
de Rugy & 25 & 25 & 26 & 49 & 14 & 37 & 11 & 15 & 16 \\
Valls & 19 & 23 & 26 & 42 & 19 & 29 & 11 & 15 & 9 \\
Peillon & 19 & 23 & 27 & 40 & 20 & 30 & 15 & 15 & 8 \\
Montebourg & 19 & 20 & 26 & 47 & 19 & 35 & 17 & 18 & 9 \\
Hamon & 23 & 17 & 30 & 43 & 15 & 27 & 11 & 23 & 9 \\
Électeur & 37 & 51 & 52 & 78 & 28 & 58 & 25 & 30 & 17
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
Ce qui permet de dresser la matrice de concordance suivante :

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay I added some text after the table and wrote another table then. The thing is that the last text was displaced above these two tables although it was placed between.
Furthermore how to get rid of the lateral lines ?

Comment: For the lateral lines, remove the `showframe` option of `geometry`. This was only to visualise the table doesn't overflow into the margin. For the placement of the second table, it's my fault: I should have used the table placement option `[!htb]`  instead of `[!ht]`. Please let me know if it is not enough.